# How to stroke a line in ios with increasing stroke size?

Tags: ios, path, drawing, stroke

i am developing a simple paint app, if we stroke path using

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(cacheContext, point1.x, point1.y);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(cacheContext, ctrl1_x, ctrl1_y, ctrl2_x, ctrl2_y, point2.x, point2.y);
CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);
```

stroke size remain the same, i want my stroke to wide in the end